check file exists on server or not using download url before downloading
I have a program that gets a set of URLs for csv files hosted online on a particular web server. The program needs to retrieve these files and save them on the local machine.
Normally, I would simply use WebClient.DownloadFile() for this. However, sometimes some URLs I am given are for files that don't exist on the server... either they were removed or not uploaded yet. In this situation, instead of a typical 404 response (or other error — which would cause an exception I could process), this server will 302 redirect to an error page that gives a 200 OK. That means the DownloadFile() method happily saves the html content of the error page in the csv file.
I need to work around this bad-behaving server.
Instead, I'm trying to send an initial HEAD request to see if the file exists, and download it only after. As a test, I have this sample with one hard-coded URL:
public static void Main()
{
    var fileUrl = "https://www.ffiec.gov/npw/FinancialReport/ReturnFinancialReportCSV?rpt=FRY9C&id=1123944&dt=20240331";

    if (URLExists(fileUrl))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading file");
        try
        {
            var location = @"C:\Users\Downloads\FRY9C\";
            var fileSaveUrl = location + "testFile.csv";
            using WebClient cln = new WebClient();
            cln.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            cln.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            cln.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a test!");

            cln.DownloadFile(fileUrl, fileSaveUrl);
        }
        catch {}
    }
}

public static bool URLExists(string url)
{
    using WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Timeout = 1200; // miliseconds
    webRequest.Method = "HEAD";

    try
    {
        using HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        return true;
    }
    catch {}
    return false;
}

But I can't get it to work the way I expect. How can I fix this?

Ken, when there is no file, system downloading file with error in it like an image in my question. Is there any way we can avoid it?

I need to download multiple files everyday if it exists in my local machine or not. All I get is URLs for those files and some of the files might not be available during my download time and some of them are. when there is no file for the given URL on server or browser I am getting different data in csv file. Please see the Sample data above. Is there ay way to check file exists before I download from server to my local..

You should make it clear in your question that you want to know if the file exists on the server, not the local machine. And the answer is no, you can only try downloading it and deal with the error if it doesn't exist.

sorry for not making it clear. Is there anyway we can check file after download and delete them if data is wrong?

Your question is all over the place. What exactly are you asking? You've gone from asking about a file existing to asking about checking if some unknown data is wrong. What specifically are you asking about here? Do you want to know about whether a file exists or not? How do you know whether the data is wrong or not before you download it and look at the data?

I want to know if file exists or not on server before downloading it and you mentioned its not possible. When I am trying to download file which is not present in server, I am receiving a file with weird html data in it. Now my question is after downloading the file can we read data in file and make sure if some keywords present in file then delete it? I hope my question is clear.

No, your question is not clear. That's why I've left all these comments asking you to explain it. Please [edit] your post and ask a clear and specific question, so that we can try to help. You keep changing your mind about what you want to know, and it's impossible to answer the different questions you keep asking.

I modified my question. if still you don't understand then I don't know how to explain it. My actual question is different but when you said its not possible to check file exists or not on server before downloading it, then I changed my question to implement what i want. I hope this gives you more clarity.

I've rolled back your most recent edit. You totally changed the entire context of the question, which would invalidate the answer you've received. That is unfair to the person who wrote that answer. In addition, it could be harmful to that user, as their answer would now be totally wrong and could be downvoted for that reason. If you have a totally different question, use the Ask Question button to ask it.

We aslo need to know more than "Can't get it to work the way I expect". What does it do? What results to you observe, and how are they different from your hypothosis? (This is the Science part of "Computer Science").

The concept is flawed.
I wouldn't expect a web site that doesn't do 404's the proper way to understand a HEAD request instead of a GET. You'll probably have to download the file regardless, check the downloaded data to be sure it's reasonable, and remove the file if it's not reasonable.
If there's a downstream system that might respond poorly to this plan, you may need to download the url into memory and check it there, before deciding to write it to the drive.
If you really want to be efficient, you can get the HTTP response stream and read just the first 100 characters or so (maybe look up how much is buffered normally by the underlying system and read that first buffer). Then continue processing (or not) from there. This is likely to out-perform two separate HTTP requests anyway, and it removes the possibility a file status will change in between the two requests.

var FilePath; //your CSV file path

if (File.Exists(FilePath))
{
    //handle your existing code here
}
else
{
    //handle your does not exist code here
}

you need to use
using System.IO;


This is not working. Even file exists its returning false only.
if (File.Exists(fileUrl))
{
try
{
var location = "C:\Users\Downloads\FRY9C\";
var fileSaveUrl = location + "testFile.csv";
WebClient cln = new WebClient();
cln.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
cln.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
cln.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a test!");
cln.DownloadFile(fileUrl, fileSaveUrl);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
}

var location = "C:\Users\Downloads\FRY9C";
try this code. Let me know what happens

parangat, I want to know if the file exists on the server, not the local machine

File.Exists() is pretty much always the wrong approach.

@JoelCoehoorn: I don't know if you're the one who DV'd this question, but this answer wasn't totally wrong based on the question at the time this answer was posted. The OP didn't indicate anything at all about wanting to know on the server. The post history can show you what a mess this has been from the start.

@KenWhite File.Exists() is almost always wrong on the local system, too.

@JoelCoehoorn: OK. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't a misunderstanding about the answer and the mess of the question. Not criticizing, just making sure you'd seen the question's original form.
